# Concat two List<T>'s where a field value in each is equal

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

```
class Person
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }

    public Person(String firstName String lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName 
        LastName = lastName;
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    List<Person> males = new List<Person>();

    males.Add(new Person() {FirstName = "Fred", LastName = "Blogs"});
    males.Add(new Person() {FirstName = "John", LastName = "James"});
    males.Add(new Person() {FirstName = "Harry", LastName = "Adams"});
    males.Add(new Person() {FirstName = "Peter", LastName = "Blogs"});

    List<Person> females = new List<Person>();

    females.Add(new Person() {FirstName = "Mary", LastName = "Blogs"});
    females.Add(new Person() {FirstName = "Anne", LastName = "James"});
    females.Add(new Person() {FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Doe"});

    List<Person> results = new List<Person>();

    results = males.Concat(females)...; // This is where I stumble ??
}
```

The `List<Person> results` needs to contain all rows where `males.LastName` and `females.LastName` exist in both lists.

I.E. `List<Person> results` should contain...

```
    FirstName = "Fred", LastName = "Blogs"});
    FirstName = "John", LastName = "James"});
    FirstName = "Peter", LastName = "Blogs"});
    FirstName = "Mary", LastName = "Blogs"});
    FirstName = "Anne", LastName = "James"});
```

Note: **Harry Adams** and **Jane Doe** should be excluded as their last names are not in both lists.

(In other words, if my favorite beer company ruled the world I would need something like:

```
`results = males.Concat(female).Where(males.LastName == female.LastName);`
```

and it would figure it out...Ah! if only)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are lots of people, you need it to be cheap to test whether a person is to be kept (i.e. has a shared name) or discarded. You can do this by creating a HashSet up front:

```
var allMaleLastNames = males.Select(m => m.LastName);
var allFemaleLastNames = females.Select(f => f.LastName);

var uniqueSharedLastNames = new HashSet<string>(
    allMaleLastNames.Intersect(allFemaleLastNames));

var result = males.Concat(females)
    .Where(p => uniqueSharedLastNames.Contains(p.LastName));
```

Comment: And this seems to be lightning!! @Selman22 I'm marking this as the correct answer as it's so fast. - Thanks both.

Answer (score 4):

```
var result = males.Concat(females).Where(p => males.Any(x => p.LastName == x.LastName) && 
                                             females.Any(x => p.LastName == x.LastName))
                                 .ToList();
```

Here is the full code that gives the expected result:

```
[Test]
public void LINQTest()
{
     List<Person> males = new List<Person>();

     males.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Fred", LastName = "Blogs" });
     males.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "James" });
     males.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Harry", LastName = "Adams" });
     males.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Peter", LastName = "Blogs" });

     List<Person> females = new List<Person>();

     females.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Mary", LastName = "Blogs" });
     females.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Anne", LastName = "James" });
     females.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Doe" });

     List<Person> results = new List<Person>();

     var result = males.Concat(females).Where(p => males.Any(x => p.LastName == x.LastName) &&
                                                   females.Any(x => p.LastName == x.LastName))
                                       .ToList();

        Assert.AreEqual(result.Count, 5); // true
}
```

Alternatively you can use Intersect and Contains like this, It might be much faster.

```
 var names = males.Select(p => p.LastName)
                  .Intersect(females.Select(p => p.LastName))
                  .ToList();
var result = males.Concat(females)
                    .Where(p =>names.Contains(p.LastName))
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: You don't brew beer do you?? - Great stuff. I couldn't see the wood for the trees - spent hours trying different things and yours is so simple...Thanks.

Comment: Although this works, I have just applied it to the real data which contains some 152,000 males and 45,000 females and it's gone away to think for a very long time. Is there a method that's faster?

Comment: @gaw, I have updated my answer,try again.and let me know if it's much faster :)

Comment: Yep, that's much faster in that it returned within 22 secs as apposed to 'I gave up waiting after 10 mins' - Thanks again.